# PHP ImageMagick - How centering inside line and block with automatically selected font size functionality

Tags: php, imagemagick

PHP 5.4. 
All welcome, I apply a solution based on [source](https://gist.github.com/clifgriffin/728cc3a4ce7b81fa2d8a)  where a text block is set and the size of the text is automatically selected depending on the length of the text [download zip](https://yadi.sk/d/KExniPdnz1N1cw)
It is necessary now that the text is centered inside the specified box and line, clearly here in screenshots, and also correctly rotate the text

screenshots:

[image]

```
 function autofit_text_to_image( $canvas_image_filename = false, $dest_filename = 'output.jpg', $text = '', $starting_font_size = 60, $max_width = 500, $max_height = 500, $x_pos = 0, $y_pos = 0, $font_file = false,$font_color = 'black',$rotate = 0, $line_height_ratio = 1, $dest_format = 'jpg' ) {

// Bail if any essential parameters are missing
if ( ! $canvas_image_filename || ! $dest_filename || empty($text) || ! $font_file || empty($font_color) || empty($max_width) || empty($max_height) ) return false;

// Do we have a valid canvas image?
if ( ! file_exists($canvas_image_filename) ) return;

$canvas_handle = fopen( $canvas_image_filename, 'rb' );

// Load image into Imagick
$NewImage = new Imagick();
$NewImage->readImageFile($canvas_handle);

// Instantiate Imagick utility objects
$draw = new ImagickDraw();
$pixel = new ImagickPixel( $font_color );

// Load Font 
$font_size = $starting_font_size;
$draw->setFont($font_file);
$draw->setFontSize($font_size);
$draw->setFillColor($font_color);
//$draw->setFillColor('red');
// Holds calculated height of lines with given font, font size
$total_height = 0;

$countall=0;
// Run until we find a font size that doesn't exceed $max_height in pixels
while (( 0 == $total_height || $total_height > $max_height )) {
        $countall=$countall+1;

    if ( $total_height > 0 ) $font_size--; // we're still over height, decrement font size and try again

    $draw->setFontSize($font_size);

    // Calculate number of lines / line height
    // Props users Sarke / BMiner: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5746537/how-can-i-wrap-text-using-imagick-in-php-so-that-it-is-drawn-as-multiline-text

    //$words = preg_split('%\s%', $text, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
    $words =preg_split( '%\s%', $text, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY );

    $lines = array();
    $i = 0;
    $line_height = 0;
$one=1;


    while ( count($words) > 0 ) { 
        $one=$one+1;

        $metrics = $NewImage->queryFontMetrics( $draw, implode(' ', array_slice($words, 0, ++$i)));
        $line_height = max( $metrics['textHeight'], $line_height );


    if ( $metrics['textWidth'] > $max_width || count($words) < $i ) {
// this indicates long words and forces the font to decrease in the first loop
if($i == 1){
    $total_height = $max_height + 1;
    continue 2;
}
$lines[] = implode( ' ', array_slice($words, 0, --$i) );
$words = array_slice( $words, $i );
$i = 0;
}   

    }

    $total_height = count($lines) * $line_height * $line_height_ratio;

    if ( $total_height === 0 ) return false; // don't run endlessly if something goes wrong
}

// Writes text to image
for( $i = 0; $i < count($lines); $i++ ) {
    $NewImage->annotateImage( $draw, $x_pos, $y_pos + ($i * $line_height * $line_height_ratio), $rotate, $lines[$i] );  
}

$NewImage->setImageFormat($dest_format);
$result = $NewImage->writeImage($dest_filename);

return $result;
}

//The file on which we impose the image
$canvas_image_filename = 'test.jpeg';

$text = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, sed deleniti intellegebat cu, et ius molestiae abhorreant reprehendunt. Ex eius mollis adipiscing vix, audire theophrastus has et, malorum numquam sea et. 
Ut vel vidit falli, in error inermis argumentum per, et doctus necessitatibus vel. 
Ut has tota gloriatur, eum ad tale voluptua deserunt. Mel iriure deleniti forensibus at.';

// We load the font
$text ="Little text";
$font_file = 'Oswald-Regular.ttf';
$font_color = 'black';
//image

// Directory from the root
$dirfile='/home/xxxxx/xxxxxxx.com/htdocs/www/xxxx/';
$gimg=str_replace(".", "",microtime(TRUE)); 
if (!file_exists($dirfile.'test/')) {
if (!mkdir($dirfile.'test/', 0755, true)) {  die('Eror');}
}
$file_save=$dirfile.'test/'.$gimg.".jpg";
$result=autofit_text_to_image($canvas_image_filename, $file_save, $text, 60, 399, 290, 350, 128, $font_file,$font_color,0);
```